# Ошибка: During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135 при вызове функции с Opencv

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Я переустанавливал WIndows, qt у меня находиться тут:

```
G:\qt
```

OpenCv тут:

```
G:\qt\opencv\opencv
```

По правде говоря началось все с того что так же не запускалась моя библиотека, она использовала opencv. Потом я создал тестовый проект, подключил туда opencv. При подкл путей библиотеки opencv все норм. Но только я начинаю переменную или функцию из opencv писать, программа выкидает данную ошибку. Я уже знаю я задавал похожий вопрос, но тогда я на него забил, потому что его можно было обходить, но сейчас эту проблему никак не обойдешь + это немного другая ситуация. Писал в переменной окружения PATH:

```
G:\qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin
```

не помогает.
Мой профайл тестового проекта:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled13
TEMPLATE = app


DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS




SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

#Подключение OpenCv
PUTH_TO_OPENCV = "G:\qt\opencv\opencv\build\bin"
DEFINES += PUTH_TO_OPENCV=\\\"$$PUTH_TO_OPENCV\\\"
INCLUDEPATH += G:\qt\opencv\opencv\build\include

LIBS += $$PUTH_TO_OPENCV\libopencv_core320.dll
LIBS += $$PUTH_TO_OPENCV\libopencv_highgui320.dll
LIBS += $$PUTH_TO_OPENCV\libopencv_imgcodecs320.dll
LIBS += $$PUTH_TO_OPENCV\libopencv_imgproc320.dll
LIBS += $$PUTH_TO_OPENCV\libopencv_features2d320.dll
LIBS += $$PUTH_TO_OPENCV\libopencv_calib3d320.dll
LIBS += $$PUTH_TO_OPENCV\libopencv_videoio320.dll
LIBS += $$PUTH_TO_OPENCV\libopencv_video320.dll
LIBS += $$PUTH_TO_OPENCV\opencv_ffmpeg320.dll
LIBS += -lgdi32
LIBS += -lkernel32
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>;
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat image; //если это убрать то все будет впорядке
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    //startbot();
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Так а все требуемые dll надо потом скопировать в папку с собранной программой.

Comment: Так а почему раньше работало. Может надо что то в переменные среды записать, только я пробовал в PATH записывать путь к opencv и ничего